# Adding text between sentence in RTB

Tags: c#, text, richtextbox

My Code:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "this is a text";
        }
    }
```

My problem is whenever I press CTRL + Q, the text will be added at the end of the sentence but not where the IBeam is. I want it to be added at where the IBeam is. I don't know how to make the text be added at where the IBeam is. I hope you guys understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're actually *appending the text.* The behavior would be expected. However, if you *insert the text*, you'll get what you want:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart,
    "this is a text");
```

Take note to the documentation of [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it states:

> If no text is selected in the control, this property indicates the insertion point, or caret, for new text.

Comment: @Hafiz, not a problem. I'm glad I could be of assistance!